Angular - reusable formgroup select component cannot set default value
I have angular reusable select component that accepts formControlName as @Input. and renders select component and options are passed as child component and rendered inside <ng-content>.
select.component.ts
import {Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';
import {faChevronDown} from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectComponent),
    }
  ]
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() formControlName: string;
  public formControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  public onChange: (_: any) => void = () => {};
  public onTouched: () => void = () => {}


  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

   writeValue(obj: any): void {
         this.formControl.setValue(obj);
    }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(disabled: boolean): void {
    disabled ? this.formControl.disable() : this.formControl.enable();
  }

  protected readonly faChevronDown = faChevronDown;
}


select.component.html
<component-label><ng-content select="[slot=label]"></ng-content></component-label>
<div class="input-container">
  <div class="left-icon"> <ng-content select="[slot=left-icon]"></ng-content></div>
  <select class="form-input highlight-on-error" [formControl]="formControl" (change)="onChange(formControl.value)" >
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </select>
  <div class="right-icon"><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon></div>
</div>
<component-error-message [controlName]="formControlName"></component-error-message>

Usage of this component is simple, it will receive form control from FormGroup as formControlName, in some cases form control will have default value setted. In that case writeValue will receive obj as param and it is correctly passed, but setValue won't be called and select have empty value.
Usage
this.formBuilder.group({
      nationality: [this.entry?.nationality === '' ? null : this.entry?.nationality]
    });

<component-select formControlName="nationality">
      <ng-container slot="label">{{ 'NATIONALITY_LABEL' | translate }}</ng-container>
      <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
      <option [ngValue]="option.code" *ngFor="let option of countries$ | async">{{ option.name }}</option>
    </component-select>

Problem is if entry has nationality, then it should set the value. Currently it is not setted. Which part of the select component logic should I change to set the value if value is loaded before initialization of component ?

When working with custom form components, there is no need to read the form control name and other actions, it's all automatic, all we need to do is configure the component in the correct format:
import {Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';
import {faChevronDown} from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-select',
  template: `
<component-label><ng-content select="[slot=label]"></ng-content></component-label>
<div class="input-container">
  <div class="left-icon"> <ng-content select="[slot=left-icon]"></ng-content></div>
  <select class="form-input highlight-on-error" [value]="value"
     [disabled]="disabled"
     (focus)="markAsTouched()"
     (change)="onChange(formControl.value)" >
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </select>
  <div class="right-icon"><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon></div>
</div>
<component-error-message [controlName]="formControlName"></component-error-message>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectComponent),
    }
  ]
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  value: any;

  onChange = (quantity) => {};

  onTouched = () => {};

  touched = false;

  disabled = false;

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }

  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouched();
      this.touched = true;
    }
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
  }

  protected readonly faChevronDown = faChevronDown;
}

Even if the above code snippet does not work, please go through these articles to learn more on this method:
Angular Reactive Forms: Custom Form Control — Control Value Accessor (Recommended!)
Angular Custom Form Controls: Complete Guide
